# How to call MATLAB from command-line and print to stdout before exiting

Tags: matlab, command-line

I'm trying to run MATLAB scripts from command-line and am having problems getting MATLAB to return results to stdout.

When running the following command, MATLAB prints the license banner and exits without printing the message.

`matlab -nodisplay -nojvm -r "fprintf(1, 'value: %f\n', 2.0); quit;"`

*note: I am currently running Version 7.10.0.499 (R2010a) 64-bit (maci64)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I stop MATLAB from returning until after a command-line script completes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495/how-can-i-stop-matlab-from-returning-until-after-a-command-line-script-completes)

Comment: The issue with 'How can I stop Matlab from returning until after a command-line script completes?' is related to how Windows opens separate command window to execute commands without blocking terminal. Also, the use of the -wait command-line option which was the solution to that issue doesn't exist on non Windows systems.

Answer (score 8):

As was shown in this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518072/suppress-start-message-of-matlab/1518165#1518165), you can use the `-logfile` option to make a copy of all outputs to a file.

```
matlab -nodisplay -nojvm -logfile out.txt -r "fprintf(1, 'value: %f\n', 2.0); quit;"
```

On [Windows](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabwindows.html#br18mhn-1), use the `-wait` command-line options to block the execution of your script until MATLAB closes.

On [Unix](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabunix.html), you can use `sleep 5s` to sleep for 5 seconds, or use the [`wait`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-wait) command to pause execution until the process finishes:

```
#!/bin/sh
matlab -nodisplay -logfile out.txt -r "rand(3), quit"
wait $(ps | grep matlab | awk '{print $2}') && cat out.txt
```