# Jenkins: Matlab doesn't exit if error occurs

Tags: matlab, jenkins

I'm currently trying to setup Jenkins to run MATLAB Tests and I have troubles getting output sometimes. I'm calling MATLAB in a pipeline via

```
bat '"PATH/matlab" -wait -nosplash -nodesktop -nogui -r "COMMAND"'
```

If COMMAND is `exit(0)` or `exit(1)` the step ends with the correct error code. However, if an error occurs e.g. if COMMAND is `error(\'some error\')` (or simply `error`) then MATLAB seems to never return. What could be the reason of this? How can I make MATLAB return with an error code to Jenkins if an error occurs?

Comment: I believe this is because an error command in matlab reports the error to matlab, not the caller. Why do you need this? maybe there is another way

Comment: I want to prevent the build from getting stuck and also receive useful error information in case an error happens. Even if I wrap most stuff that happens in the called functions in try-catch and exit with an error code, errors still might happen during execution, of which I want to be informed.

Comment: I realized that this is not a Jenkins specific problem, but a general problem with calling matlab from the command line. I found two helpful stackoverflow questions that help me, if put together: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337067/how-do-i-quit-matlab-after-execution-is-finished-through-command -> By wrapping the COMMAND in a try-catch block directly in the bat command I can prevent matlab from staying stuck open. AND https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37830871/how-to-get-matlab-output-in-jenkins-console -> by using a logfile as workaround I can get output in the Jenkins console.