# MATLAB output to PHP variable

Tags: matlab

I have a matlab function. I have called this function from my php code and wants to receive return value of matlab function into a php variable. Please help me out.
matlab :

```
function img =TigerPrinting(udir, pdir, template)
% clc;
% clear all;
imdir = udir;
imdir=strcat(imdir,'\');
b=template;
% disp(b)
temp=imread([imdir,b]);
% disp(temp)
  pd=pdir;
  % disp(pd)
  img = '';
  p=strcat(pd,'\*.jpg');
  pd=strcat(pd,'\');
  %disp(pd)
  listing=dir(p);
  x=size(listing);
  x=x(1);
   % disp(x)
  for i=1:x
      a=imread([pd,listing(i).name]);
     % disp(a)
      d=TempMatch(a,temp);
     % disp(d)
      if d>0
         % disp(strcat('* ',b,' found in image  ',listing(i).name));
          img = strcat(img,',',listing(i).name);
      else
          % disp(strcat('* ',b,' not found in image  ',listing(i).name));
      end
  end
 display(img);
 %quit force
 end
```

this function working properly and img contains desire value

php code :

```
$command = "matlab  -wait -nojvm -nodesktop -nodisplay -r \"  TigerPrinting('".$l_udir."','".$l_pdir."','".$left_flank ."');\" ";

        $ot = exec($command);
        echo($ot);
```

but $ot echos nothing.

Comment: could you post the code you have tried?

Comment: it would be better if you include it on your post.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611195/how-to-call-matlab-from-command-line-and-print-to-stdout-before-exiting

Comment: `exec` only returns the last line of the standard output apparently (see [here](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.exec.php), you must specify its second argument which must be an array. It will be filled with the standard output...