# run Matlab code from PHP

Tags: php, matlab, backend

I am trying to build the frontend for my app using HTML and CSS. I have IIS installed and am sending a request to a PHP script that needs to execute a Matlab code.

**What the problem is?**
I can not succesfully execute the Matlab code. I woud prefer to run the code through CMD.

**What I've tried?**
I've tried the following
(A)

```
exec(matlab -nodisplay -nojvm -logfile out.txt -r "[matlabfilename]; quit;");
```

Result: nothing happens, what I expect to see is the output of matlab program in out.txt. Out.txt contains the output of the program  if I execute the above code on cmd but if I use the link in the web browser it becomes empty

(B) I've made a batch file of the cmd command that works and used

```
system("cmd /c C:\inetpub\wwwroot\beServer\prog.bat");
```

where prog.bat contains

```
matlab -nodisplay -logfile out.txt -r "main; quit;"
```

I've copied all matlab files I want to execute to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\beServer

Result:I see C:\inetpub\wwwroot\beServer>matlab -nodisplay -logfile out.txt -r "main; quit;" in the web browser but no changes in out.txt

Comment: What does `out.txt` contain in the first case?

Comment: nothing, it's blank. It will contain the output of the matlab program. For instance if I execute matlab -nodisplay -nojvm -logfile out.txt -r "fprintf(1, 'value: %f\n', 2.0); quit;" on cmd it contains 2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611195/how-to-call-matlab-from-command-line-and-print-to-stdout-before-exiting/4621554#4621554

Comment: Your question contains the sentence "out.txt contains some output text" so  I did not expect it to be empty. Please update your question and make it clear.

Comment: done with the edit. Any suggestions?